# How useEffect is called if there is a custom hook which is also using a use effect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [allrestro, setallrestro] = useState([]);
  const [filteredrestaurant, setfilteredrestaurant] = useState([]);

  const search = useState("");
  [searchValue, setsearchValue] = search;


  useEffect(() => {
    const getRestaurants = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=30.9188442&lng=75.8148262&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING");
      const json = await data.json();

      setallrestro(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setfilteredrestaurant(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setTimeout(() => {
        
      }, 10000);
      

    }
    getRestaurants();

  }, []);

  



  const isOnline = useOnline();
  if (!isOnline) {
    return <h1>You are offline</h1>
  }
```

It is working fine But when I do this

```
const Body = () => {
  
  const [allrestro, setallrestro] = useState([]);
  const [filteredrestaurant, setfilteredrestaurant] = useState([]);

  const search = useState("");
  [searchValue, setsearchValue] = search;


  
  const isOnline = useOnline();
  
  if (!isOnline) {
    
    return <h1>You are offline</h1>
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRestaurants = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=30.9188442&lng=75.8148262&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING");
      const json = await data.json();

      setallrestro(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setfilteredrestaurant(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 10000);
      

    }
    getRestaurants();

  }, []);
```

It is not working!
Is there any problem if I call useOnline above useEffect

Here is the UseOnline Hook

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";

const useOnline=()=>{
    const [state,usestate]=useState(true);
    
    console.log("outside component component")
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("outside component");
        window.addEventListener("online",()=>{usestate(true)});
        window.addEventListener("offline",()=>{usestate(false)});
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("useOnline useffect")
          }, 5000);
    },[])
    

    return state;
}
export default useOnline;
```

Can you explain also how hooks is called if there are multiple hooks inside a component?
The cycle of component runs seperately for custom hooks or is it bind to the calling fucntion?

Comment: You shouldn't do early return if you are using `hooks` after that. [READ rules of hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Hooks should be called in same exact order.Hooks are just normal functions which should follow 2 [rules](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) everything else is same as any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a custom hook in a component that calls `useEffect` is no different than calling `useEffect` in the component body. Custom hooks are meant to encapsulate logic, but otherwise work exactly the same.

An important rule in React is that all [hooks must be called at the top level](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), so you should never call them inside conditions or after early returns. So for example the rule is violated if you call:

```
if (!isOnline) { 
  return <h1>You are offline</h1>
}
```

Since if `!isOnline`, the second `useEffect` might not be called. To fix it, simply move `useEffect` above the early return.

Answer (score 0):

The `useOnline` custom hook works by calling `useEffect` to listen for the `online` and `offline` events. When the user goes online, the state is set to `true`. When the user goes offline, the state is set to `false`.

The `useEffect` hook is called in the following order:

1. All custom hooks are called.
2. All `useEffect` hooks are called in the order they are defined.

This means that the `useEffect` hook in the `Body` component will be called after the `useOnline` custom hook.

The reason why your code is not working is because the `useOnline` custom hook is returning the initial state of `true` before the `useEffect` hook in the `Body` component has a chance to run. This means that the `useEffect` hook in the `Body` component will never be called, because the `isOnline` state variable will always be `true`.

To fix this, you can move the `useOnline` custom hook into the `useEffect` hook in the `Body` component, like this:

```
const Body = () => {
  const [allrestro, setallrestro] = useState([]);
  const [filteredrestaurant, setfilteredrestaurant] = useState([]);

  const search = useState("");
  [searchValue, setsearchValue] = search;

  useEffect(() => {
    const isOnline = useOnline();

    if (!isOnline) {
      return <h1>You are offline</h1>;
    }

    const getRestaurants = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=30.9188442&lng=75.8148262&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING");
      const json = await data.json();

      setallrestro(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setfilteredrestaurant(json?.data?.cards[5]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants);
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 10000);
    };

    getRestaurants();
  }, []);
};
```

**The cycle of the component run separately for custom hooks or is it bind to the calling function**

Custom hooks are essentially functions that return React state and other values. They are not separate components. When a custom hook is used in a component, the code in the custom hook is executed within the context of the calling component. This means that the custom hook has access to the component's state and other values.